# how does this sort of python indexing: 'print(X_train[y_train == 0][0])' work in python?

Tags: python

I've training data X_train with #sample=60,000 and #features=784. And corresponding labels y_train with len(y_train)=60,000.

I am not getting how is the following piece of code working:

```
print(X_train[y_train == 0][0])
```

It's basically the indexing that I'm not getting.

 I tried the following to understand it(considering what y_train==0 would result into.):

`print(X_train[False True False False][0])` 
but it's resulting into errors. Any guide will be appreciated.

here's the output: [image]

Comment: `X_train[False True False False][0]` is not valid Python. Lists are separated by `,` and, besides, you are missing square brackets to denote `list`. Provided `X_train` has only 4 rows, you could use `X_train[[False, True, False, False]][0]`.

Comment: @jpp so this would work only when the dimension would match.

Comment: Yes, dimensions should match. If they don't you might get `VisibleDeprecationWarning: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0...`

Comment: @jpp is the any 'axes' sort of thing which is playing some role for 0 in 'X_train[y_train==i][0]' ? pls explain bcs I'm understanding y_train==i will return a list with length = len(y_train) filled with True/False and the run time environment is not accepting True/False as indices for X_train explicitly.

Comment: Are you sure you get a list? Try `type(y_train==i)`. What do you see?

Comment: for `y_train==0` I'm getting following - 
`Out[114]: array([False,  True, False, ..., False, False, False])`

Comment: Exactly. So `y_train==i will return a list` isn't correct. It returns a NumPy array, an important point to note.

Comment: @jpp please tell me how is this indexing working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided `y_train` is a `list`, `y_train == 0` will always evaluate to `False` since a `list` does not equate `0`.  Also, since `False` is equivalent of `0`, your line evaluates to `X_train[0][0]` which returns the first item of the first list from `X_train`.

As @jpp mentioned, `X_train[False True False False]` is not valid Python syntax as a square bracket that follows an object denotes the `index` or `slice`, not a `list` (and even then you're still missing commas).

If however you wanted to say loop through the 60,000 items in `y_train` and get the corresponding `X_train` item where `y_train == 0`, then you want to do something like this instead:

```
for y in y_train:
    if y == 0:    
        print(X_train[y][0])
```

Comment: this way it will return 1 value at a time and if it is done alike: X_train[y_train==0][0] it will return those values in the form of a matrix.

Comment: Unless your `X_Train` is more than 2 dimensions, I doubt `X_Train[y_train==0][0]` will return a matrix for you.  It's hard to speculate without some sample data or structure though.

Comment: 'for i in range(10):                                                                                                                   
      img = X_train[y_train == i][0].reshape(28, 28)'                                            this is the code @ldlehands

Answer (score 2):

Give it a test!

```
>>> sample_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> sample_list[True]
2
>>> sample_list[False]
1
```

I believe you can deduct the fact that `True` is equivalent to `1` and `False` is equivalent to `0`.

Additional test:

```
>>> False == 0
True
>>> True == 1
True
```

I believe this would help.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here, mainly syntax related:

1. You are confusing `__getitem__`, which is expressed via syntactic sugar `[]` with the list constructor `[]`.
2. You need to separate elements in your `list` with `,`.
3. You should index via a NumPy array rather than a list to avoid `True` being considered `1` index / `False` as `0`.

So you can *try*:

```
mask = np.array([False, True, False, False])
res = X_train[mask][0]
```

But this may only work if `X_train` only has 4 rows. If it doesn't error and the rows are different you may meet:

> VisibleDeprecationWarning: boolean index did not match indexed array
>   along dimension 0

Answer (score 1):

I would like to see a complete, minimal and verifiable example.

Based on what I see now is that X_train is a 2-dimensional array (or list) and therefore you need to provide two separate indices. Each entry in the list contains another list that you get as the print output.

y_train == 0 will evaluate either to True or False depending on the value of the y_train variable. It is guaranteed that True may be implicitly converted to 1 and False to a 0. So your other index (y_train == 0) is either 0 or 1

Answer (score 0):

Although, I have already accepted an answer but I also want to write here what is exactly I was asking for:
 Let's take an example of a DataFrame (a pandas' data structure):
`import pandas
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':[1,2,3,2,1,9],'B':[3,2,1,4,5,6],'C':[4,5,5,4,6,4]})`
after running the above script the output will be as follows:
 [image] 
Now, suppose we want to retrieve all the information for all those rows where C==4.For such case, I'm writing here, for the sake of simplicity, a two step script:
1. `list_true_false = df['C']==4` 
Output:
`list_true_false = [True, False, False, True, False, True]`
 **list_true_false** will be a True/False valued list length equal to length(C). and when we will do the following:
 2.`df[list_true_false]`
 all those rows where indices of *list_true_false* hold 'True' value would be returned.
[image]. 
So the above two steps are often merged as follows to save some scripting and time:
 
`df[df['C']==4]`. 
 In the question, the line `X_train[False True False False]` didn't work because there should be a list for the index of 'X' rather than bare True/False values:
 `X[[True False False True .... False True]]`